# Power Pivot fails to load on restart

Tags: microsoft-excel

For some reason I have to go to options / ad ins/ com-add ins/ PowerPivot each time I restart Excel.

Also it takes me 2 or 3 attempts to enable it in order to get it to work each time. This is on Excel 2013 on Windows 10.

Is there any way I can have PowerPivot load automatically each time I start excel? So I don't have to waste my time this way.

Comment: Did you get any error messages? Did you open a blank Power Pivot window or an existed data model?

Comment: No, I got no messages. The Power Pivot tab simply isn't there. Then I have to go and load it. I want it to load automatically each time I start excel if that's possible.